# Inserting footline into section page

Tags: beamer, header-footer, tikz-styles

I like to insert footlines into my `\section{}` pages. For now, it only shows them on the main content pages. Also, as my sections have a darker background, the footline should be white.

How is this possible?

Current *.sty:

```
--- Sections ---

\if@doSectionPage\@empty 
\else
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background dark}{bg=backgrounddark}
  \begin{frame}[plain]
    \vspace{2em}\usebeamerfont{section title}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background]\node[anchor=west, white, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\insertsectionHEAD};
\end{tikzpicture}

  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach, instead of inserting a footline, why remove it in the first place? So instead of using a `plain` frame, remove only the headline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begingroup
    \setbeamercolor{background dark}{bg=backgrounddark}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \vspace{2em}\usebeamerfont{section title}
        \vspace*{-\headheight}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=west, blue, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\insertsection};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}



\begin{document}
    \section{test}

    \begin{frame}
        bla
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]